# C# - Rewrite If-Else statement with similar code to ternary condition

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements

I would like to optimize the following code. How to rewrite the following

```cs
if (cmd.InvoiceRun.BlancoInvoice)
{
    commands.Add(new GenerateBlancoInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc));
}
else
{
    commands.Add(new GenerateInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc));
}
```

to an if/else statement to a ternary statement?

I have tried

```cs
cmd.InvoiceRun.BlancoInvoice 
    ? commands.Add(new GenerateInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc))
    : commands.Add(new GenerateBlancoInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc));
```

but that't not accepted due to
`Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await expression, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`.

I would expect that it's possible though, would I need to take the `commands.Add` before the ternary operator?

Comment: Why would you want to rewrite a perfectly good if/else to a ternary operator?

Comment: Create the objects using the ternary operator & use a single commands.Add call. But as @Sweeper said - this seems a pointless "optimisation" - the code is clear as it stands & the compiler will probably optimise it anyway.

Comment: What is the common base class or interface both classes implement?

Comment: @Sweeper I like the compactness of ternary statements (3 lines instead of 6). Indeed it's not a major optimization, I was just curious if it's possible :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter both command inherit from the same base class `InvoiceCommand`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is not possibile in c#. You need to move commands.Add before the ternary operator

```cs
commands.Add(cmd.InvoiceRun.BlancoInvoice 
    ? new GenerateBlancoInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc)
    : new GenerateInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc));
```

Also in this case I prefer the if-else statement because it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the [conditional operator ?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) directly to make an assignment, you can use it for code that returns something. So you can use it to determine what type of command will be added:

```
InvoiceCommand command = cmd.InvoiceRun.BlancoInvoice 
    ? new GenerateBlancoInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc)
    : new GenerateInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc);
commands.Add(command);
```

Comment: Actually you can, but you have to cast one or the other and then it looks ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this work

```
commands.Add(cmd.InvoiceRun.BlancoInvoice 
    ? new GenerateBlancoInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc)
    : new GenerateInvoiceCommand(invoice, cmd.Owner, cmd.CreatedAtUtc));
```